# OLAP cube designing: runtime generated measures

Tags: design-patterns, olap, mondrian

I'm facing a requirement that I'm not entirely sure that can be achieved by pure OLAP designing (anyway, my OLAP knowledge is SO small).

I have a dimension table such as

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS TMP_DEBUG_OLAP_44_BUILDING;
CREATE TABLE TMP_DEBUG_OLAP_44_BUILDING AS
SELECT 1 AS building_id,'Building 1' AS building_name
UNION ALL
SELECT 2 AS building_id,'Building 2' AS building_name
;
```

and  a table fact (fact-1) such as

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS TMP_DEBUG_OLAP_44_FACTS;
CREATE TABLE TMP_DEBUG_OLAP_44_FACTS AS
SELECT 1 AS building_id,10 AS budget_amount,11 AS estimate_amount
UNION ALL
SELECT 2 AS building_id,12 AS budget_amount,13 AS estimate_amount
;
```

and a factor-conversion fact table (fact-2) such as

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS TMP_DEBUG_OLAP_44_FACT_FACTORS;
CREATE TABLE TMP_DEBUG_OLAP_44_FACT_FACTORS AS
SELECT 'DK' AS country_id,1.0 AS FACTOR
UNION ALL
SELECT 'MX' AS country_id,1.5 AS FACTOR
;
```

I've been asked to generate a measure per tuple [Measures].[Budget amount]_vs_country, so that it adds, per tuple in fact-2, a measure, multipling [Measures].[Budget amount] * factor_value.

Example: fact-table-1 first row is building_id=1, I need 3 measures: [Measures].[Budget amount], budget-amount*1.0(DK) and budget-amount*1.5(MX).

Now, if another country is added into the tables, there's a new tuple, hence, a new measure.

Is there any way this could be achieved without modifying the cube?

Thanks and regards!

Comment: Alternatively, if there was a way to pass input parameters to get a single measure, with the factor applied to the chosen country, shall suffice. Yet, my explotation platform is JPivot, which lacks the ability of user-input.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your Budget measure is a semi-additive measure because it is additive on the Building dimension but not on the Country dimension.  Semi-additive measures are usually solved with Calculated Measures.